# How to capture screenshots while writing the UI test cases in android studio

Tags: android, kotlin

Q. How to capture screenshots while writing the UI test cases in android studio using espresso tool, kotlin language and robolectric test cases using act, arrange and assert
For mobile android application -
1. I am writing the test cases using android studio, kotlin language and robolectric form- act, arrange and assert android UI Test cases.
Running test cases on - emulator, real device
In act- login the app
In arrange - Go to specific screen and perform click function
In assert- validating the UI with specific fields and column text fields and value.
I want to capture the screenshots in between where the assert commands failed or code exit with an error. I was new to kotlin but now learnt how to write the code, need help in how to capture the screenshot in this case.
I had searched helping code on google and try out to find some hint but didn't get much to understand.
Below is the code -

```
@Test
fun loginSuccess() {
// arrange
// act
         onView(withId(R.id.login)).perform(click())

// assert
onView(withId(R.id.logoImg)).check(matches(isDisplayed()))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this article. There is not a single method which handles everything for you.https://medium.com/@mohitgupta92/custom-failure-handler-for-android-espresso-c8c99eb65a32